# Created a Passbook (event type) with relevantDate is not showing up on lock screen

Tags: ios, wallet

I'm creating an apple passbook for events, using this php library (https://github.com/tschoffelen/PHP-PKPass).

It opens fine on my phone and everything but even though I'm using the relevanceDate as it says here (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Creating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH4-SW53).

I tried with todays date and tomorrows date but still is not coming up on the lock screen.

This is the pass.json

```
{
        "description": "Event Confirmation",
        "formatVersion": 1,
        "organizationName": "EventTest",
        "passTypeIdentifier": "pass.com.eventtest.confirmation",
        "serialNumber": "#########",
        "teamIdentifier": "######",
        "expirationDate": "2017-05-04T23:00:00Z",
        "relevantDate": "2017-04-28T07:00Z",
        "eventTicket": {
            "headerFields": [{
                "key": "eventHeader",
                "label": "TEST",
                "value": ""
            }],
            "secondaryFields": [{
                "key": "nameSecondaryFields",
                "label": "Name",
                "value": "Federico Giust"
            }],
            "auxiliaryFields": [{
                "key": "locAuxiliaryFields",
                "label": "Brixton Academy",
                "value": "Brixton, London, UK"
            }, {
                "key": "startdateAuxiliaryFields",
                "label": "Start Date",
                "value": "28-04-2017"
            }, {
                "key": "enddateAuxiliaryFields",
                "label": "End Date",
                "value": "05-05-2017"
            }],
            "backFields": [{
                "key": "eventBackFields",
                "label": "TEST",
                "value": "Test Project - Local"
            }, {
                "key": "locBackFields",
                "label": "Brixton Academy",
                "value": "Brixton, London, UK"
            }, {
                "key": "startdateBackFields",
                "label": "Start Date",
                "value": "28-04-2017"
            }, {
                "key": "enddateBackFields",
                "label": "End Date",
                "value": "05-05-2017"
            }, {
                "key": "eventDescription",
                "label": "Description",
                "value": "Project Description goes here"
            }, {
                "key": "eventURL",
                "label": "Website",
                "value": "https:\/\/www.eventtest.com"
            }, {
                "key": "eventT&C",
                "label": "Terms and Conditions",
                "value": "Terms & Conditions"
            }]
        },
        "barcode": {
            "altText": "4156452",
            "format": "PKBarcodeFormatQR",
            "message": "4156452",
            "messageEncoding": "iso-8859-1"
        },
        "backgroundColor": "rgb(255,255,255)",
        "foregroundColor": "rgb(000, 000, 000)",
        "logoText": "Test Project - Local"
    }
```

Anybody knows how far in advance a passbook is supposed to appear on the lock screen? Am I missing another field?

I already have location services enabled and wallet notifications enabled and it works for other passbooks.

Thanks

Comment: For an event ticket, both the relevant date and the loctation need to match for the notification to trigger.

Comment: @PassKit According to the Apple Developer documentation you can use Date and/or Location to display the notifications. It doesn't say anywhere when they are Time Based notifications how far in advance it is displayed on the lock screen (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Creating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH4-SW53)